# TFS command line check in

Tags: command-line, tfs

I modified some of files which is under TFS, saved changes and tried to checked it in with the following command:

```
checkin "filename" /override:"1" /noprompt /comment:"some comment here"
```

and get the error:

```
There is no pending change for "filename"
```

Does anybody knows what should i do to check it in successfully?

---

Solution:
If you modify a file not in Visual Studio, it is necessary to do checkout before checkin to avoid this issue.

Answer (score 3):

Just a guess, but it sounds like tf.exe doesn't know which workspace to make this checkin operation on. Look at the documentation for `tf.exe workspace` and `tf.exe workspaces`

Comment: Thanks. checkout before checkin help me to avoid this issue.